# Angular Material mat-expansion-panel-body style not being applied

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I have the following css in my component's css file:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}
```

And, so I would expect to see this rule (even if overridden) to show up for the following dom element:

```
<div class="mat-expansion-panel-body">...</div>
```

But, all I see being applied in dev tools is:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
  padding: 0 24px 16px;
}
```

I noticed that this element does not have the ***_ngcontent-c19*** class that the other *host* elements do, and so I assume this is a case of view encapsulation.

However, after reading around with the deprecation of ::ng-deep and /deep/ and other encapsulation piercing constructs to be deprecated, what is a better solution to styling this element from within my component's css file?

Comment: What version of Angular and Material are you using?

Comment: Angular (6.1.7) / Material(6.2.1)

Answer (score 23):

I set up `::ng-deep` in component css, it worked in my side.

```
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-body{
     padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: very clever, but from now every expansion panel body in child elements will be styled alike this, which is not wanted

Comment: Put the ng-deep inside a :host{} if you want the changes to effect to only this component.
Or put the ng-deep inside a className and use this class in the required expansion panel, so that it is affecting only this expansion panel

Answer (score 17):

### for `"@angular/material": "^10.2.7"`

You add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` property into your @Component decorator

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['...'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class examplePage{}
```

Then this CSS will work fine with !important

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Note that `::ng-deep` and `/deep/` will not work on the new version of angular/material

Answer (score 12):

One possible solution if you don't want to use ::ng-deep is to set the style in your styles.css file like so.

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

This will remove the padding, but be careful as it will remove it from all of the mat-expansion-panel-body elements. You can bypass this by setting a specific class to your expansion panel and then doing something like this in styles.css

```
.my-special-class .mat-expansion-panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}
```

In this case you don't even need !important. Here is the example of this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a6necw

Comment: I think this is a valid alternative. However, I would like to retain the localized styling rather than creating global styles that are specific to one page/component as it's not really maintainable as the project grows. I tried to upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation for it to show yet.

Comment: I would have to agree - this is a good alternative but would prefer to keep specific styling in the module's style file.

Answer (score 6):

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-body {
     padding: 0 !important;
 }
```

Works the best, now you don't have to think about this style being applies across all your components.
Using `:host` applies it only to the current host component

Answer (score 1):

Below how it worked for me:

```
::ng-deep div.mat-expansion-panel-body {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will aggregate all the answers and give some solutions:

1. use `ng-deep` like `::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-body` in your component CSS - pretty nice solution but Angular team decided to depracte `ng-deep`
2. use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` - personally I think is the worst solution as you will set global classes which can conflict with existing, new classes or dynamic ones (like ads on some sites)
3. `component-name .mat-expansion-panel-body` in the global `styles.(s)css` - the only disadvantage is that you have to maintain the selector in case someone renames the component's selector
4. move the `.mat-expansion-panel-body { padding: 0 }` in the global `styles.(s)css` file and affect all `mat-expansion`s components from now on.

Personally I still prefer the option 1 or 3, but in my team we chose the 4th option.

Answer (score 1):

```css
Please use ngdeep code here before all inbuilt classes in angular 
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-body{
     padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use ng-deep with a custom class to avoid style propagation

```
::ng-deep .nav-expansion-panel {
   .mat-expansion-panel-content{
   .mat-expansion-panel-body {
       padding: 0 5px  !important;
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a bunch of time on this, I just made a custom css class and wrapped the mat-accordion stuff in a div.  Since I had three sections, the all have space nicely now.

this css:

```
.app-mat-accordion-vertical-margin {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

the html:

```
     <div class="app-mat-accordion-vertical-margin">
              <mat-accordion...
               ...
               ...
               </mat-accordion>
     </div>
```